# Python get current index of list comprehension without using enumerate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following data:

```
names = ['foo','bar','baz', 'spam', 'ham', 'jam']

indices =[0,2,3,4]

size = 3
```

and want to create a list of the names which index is in `indices`. The list must have the size specified in the variable `size`.

I could not achieve it by doing this (wrong length):

```
selected_names = []
selected_names = [names[i] for i in indices if len(selected_names) <= size]
# Out[5]: ['foo', 'baz', 'spam', 'ham']
```

and I don't like this solution because declaring the empty list at the beginning is not elegant.

I can do this:

```
selected_names = [names[i] for x,i in  enumerate(indices) if x <= size]
```

but that's a bit unreadable and the list length is still wrong.

Is there a correct and more beautiful way to create that list? maybe something like this?

```
#pseudo code
selected_names = [names[i] for i in indices if list_current_index < size]
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use `enumerate()`. It's Pythonic.

Comment: In your "I've achieved it by doing this code", your `if` condition did nothing. `selected_names` remains empty until the list comprehension finishes, so the check always says "Yup, the length of an empty list is `<= size`." And of course, you say you want a final `list` with `size` elements, but testing `<= size` would actually get you `size+1` elements.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thx for letting me know. I'll remove the errors from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate` wouldn't even solve this since it would cause you to stop when you'd *pulled* `size` elements, not when you'd *kept* `size` elements. The only reason it seems to work is that you use a test for `<= size` (which actually keeps `size + 1` elements), and your `indices` happens to be one element larger than `size`. If `indices` was larger, or `size` smaller, your test wouldn't work as intended.

If the goal is to keep `size` elements, without processing more elements than needed, then the simplest approach (assuming you don't mind slicing to create a small intermediate `list`, which is usually okay) is just:

```
selected_names = [names[i] for i in indices[:size]]
```

If `indices` and `size` are huge, you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) with a generator expression to avoid the intermediate slice, using less memory, but somewhat more CPU:

```
import itertools

selected_names = [names[i] for i in itertools.islice(indices, size)]
```

The fastest option I can find, avoiding any explicit looping at all, is using the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), though it involves temporaries for argument passing, which is probably a bad idea if `size` is ever going to be huge (10s of thousands and up):

```
import operator

selected_names = operator.itemgetter(*indices[:size])(names)
```

This creates an `itemgetter` callable that will look up the first `size` elements from `indices`, then immediately calls it on `names`, returning a `tuple` of all the values (wrap the `itemgetter` call in `list` if you need a mutable `list` result instead of a `tuple`). It also avoids all Python level loops in CPython; a loop still occurs at the C layer in CPython, but a loop at the C layer runs a lot faster than any loop at the Python layer. For simple `ipython` `%timeit` tests, the `operator.itemgetter` approach won, taking ~24% less time than slice + `list` comprehension (which in turn was about 9% faster than `islice` + `list` comprehension). For larger inputs (I just multiplied `indices` and `size` by 100), `operator.itemgetter` wins by a factor of 3x (slice still beats `islice`, but by a meaningless margin; the overhead in `islice` is mostly in setup, and doesn't increase meaningfully as the number of items sliced goes up).

All are equivalent to:

```
selected_names = [names[i] for i in indices][:size]
```

except they don't populate the complete `list` first, then cut it down to `size`; they get enough entries and stop immediately.